# IF + INDIRECT Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, between, excel-2016, excel-indirect

I have been trying for hours to get the `=IF(INDIRECT...` Funktion to work, but i cant get it to work.

Hope you can help me out.

I have 3 worksheets (`Calender`, `sheet1`, `sheet2` (up to 50))

In Calender I have different "inputs" like `Name(A1)`, `City(A2)`, `Number(A3)` etc.

On `A4` Ii have a booking number. This booking number refers to `sheet1` or `sheet2`

In `sheet1` and `sheet2` I have the same "inputs"

What I would like to, is when I type `sheet1` in `Calender` on `B4` it fills in `B1+B2+B3` with the info from sheet1 `A1+A2+A3`

If i insted used `sheet2`in `Calender!B4`, it would fill in the info from `sheet2`

[image: simplified]

Comment: Set B1 to `=Indirect(B4 & "!A1")` it will. It will pick up "Sheet1` from `B4` and make the string `Sheet!A1`. Indirect will interpret the string and grab the value from that `Sheet1!A1` cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it slightly more robust, add single quotes round B4, e.g. `=INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!A1")`. This will then also deal with worksheets that have spaces and other non alphanumeric characters in the name.

Comment: Thanks both of you!

How do i get rid of the #Reference when B4 is blank?

Comment: Wrap it with an IFERROR function, such as `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!A1"),"")`. This is a really useful function that converts any error into the value of the second argument, in this case a blank string

Comment: Is it possible to combine 2 cells in the function.

I got at one cell for first name and one for last name.

But how do i get them combined?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the booking reference to come from two different cells? If that is what you mean, for example, cell B4 contains first name "Joe", cell B5 contains last name "Smith", and you want to find the details on a sheet called "Joe Smith", then the formula would be `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B4&" "&B5&"'!A1"),"")`. If you meant something else, let me know!

Comment: It's fine just with one cell B4 to make the refference.

But is it possible that the "Name"  in Calendar B1 is combined with 2 cells from another sheet (B4)

In sheet1 i have 2 cells 
A1 first name
A2 last name

I would like to combine them in Calendar B1.

I have some other cells where the function would be usefull so its not just for the names.

Comment: Ok I understand. Then just concatenate two `INDIRECT` formulae together that reference each of the A1 and A2 cells, as in... `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!A1")&" "&INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!A2"),"")`

Comment: Thank you Martin

It has been a great help.

I can now combine if.error + if + indirect 
So im getting a hang on it due to the help in this thread

Comment: Last thing (hopefully)

Is it possible to insert text into the indirect function.
(HVIS(INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!B45")>=1;INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!B45")&" x "&INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!C45");"");"")&"   "&HVIS.FEJL(HVIS(INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!B46")>=1;INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!B46")&" x "&INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!C46");"");"")

Comment: Last thing (hopefully)

Is it possible to insert text into the indirect function.

=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B45")>=1;INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B45")&" x "&INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!C45");"");"")&"   "&IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B46")>=1;INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B46")&" x "&INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!C46");"");"")
                                                                                                                                     



It returns


1 x 1,5  1 x 2 

Is it possible to add m after 1,5 and 2

1 x 1,5m   1 x 2m

INDIREKTE("'"&D24&"'!B45")&....

Comment: Yes. Just add the m in the quoted text as in: `=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B45")>=1;INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B45")&" x "&INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!C45")&"m";"");"")&" "&IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B46")>=1;INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!B46")&" x "&INDIRECT("'"&D24&"'!C46")&"m";"");"")`. I think this will work but have not tested it